# pandas get_dummies cannot handle unseen labels in test data

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have a Pandas DataFrame, `train`, that I'm one-hot encoding.  It looks something like this:

```
    car
0   Mazda
1   BMW
2   Honda
```

If I use `pd.get_dummies`, I'll get this:

```
car_BMW car_Honda   car_Mazda
0   0       0           1
1   1       0           0
2   0       1           0
```

All good so far.

However, I don't have access to my test set so I need to handle the possibility that a value for `car` appears in test that wasn't seen in `train`.

Suppose `test` is this:

```
    car
0   Mazda
1   Audi
```

Then if I use `pd.get_dummies` on `test`, I get:

```
car_Audi    car_Mazda
0   0           1
1   1           0
```

Which is wrong, because I have a new column, `car_Audi` and am missing `car_BMW`.

I'd like the output of one-hot encoding `test` to be:

```
car_BMW car_Honda   car_Mazda
0   0       0           1
1   0       0           0
```

So it just ignores previously unseen values in test. I definitely don't want to create new columns for previously unseen values in test.

I've looked into `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer` but it outputs a numpy array and the order isn't clear for the columns:

```
lb = LabelBinarizer()
train_transformed = lb.fit_transform(train_df)
```

gives me back:

```
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

Any ideas here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a hard problem to solve. `LabelBinarizer` has a parameter `classes_` you can query if you want to know the position of the original labels:

```
train_transformed = lb.fit_transform(df)

print(train_transformed)
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]])

print(lb.classes_)
array(['BMW', 'Honda', 'Mazda'], dtype='<U5')
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thanks.  So I guess I can just do `temp = lb.transform(test_df); return pd.DataFrame(temp, columns=lb.classes_)`?